# Will Nodal point change if I change zoom on camera?

Tags: panorama

when I find Nodal point on my camera, and I zoom in, is it necessary to rearrange camera?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, the nodal point changes.** If it does not, its purely coincidence!

Each time you change focal-length, you will need to recompute the nodal point of your lens. Note that this is also true of focus on most lenses but the difference is not very pronounced and *should* only be noticeable when focusing at close (macro) distances.

Answer (score 1):

It does yes, because the iris diaphragm moves as you zoom (usually).

This depends on what camera/lens you have.

If the nodal point is important for your shoot, then yes you may need to rearrange.